# Three.js godrays shader

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader

Can you help me: what techniques of shaders are used to create such type of godrays: http://70ans.inra.fr/ (look at the top of the scene - there are godrays with changing color and rotation).

Maybe you can give me some kind of tutorial/ready-to-use shader or describe how to do such type of shader and animate it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You will not receive a tutorial here, but you can study [this three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_godrays.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 
I tried to study this example before, but i didn't understand how to add texture or change color of godrays. 
They always remain white.